# A struct defined in a separate header file

Tags: c, header, struct

LMlib.h

```
#ifndef LMlib_H
#define LMlib_H
#endif

#define MAX_IP_LENGTH 15         
#define MAX_TABLE_ROWS 255

struct ForwardingTableRow
{
        char address[MAX_IP_LENGTH];
        int subnetMask;
        int interface;
};

typedef struct ForwardingTableRow ForwardingTableRow;
```

LMlib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "LMlib.h"

void ReadForwardingTable(FILE* f,ForwardingTableRow * table)
{
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<MAX_TABLE_ROWS;i++)
        {
                fscanf(f,"%s %d %d",&table.address[i],&table.subnetMask[i],&table.interface[i]);
        }


}
```

Complier command:

> cc LMlib.c LMlib.h main.c -lm

Error:

```
LMlib.c: In function ‘ReadForwardingTable’:
LMlib.c:11:27: error: request for member ‘address’ in something not a structure or union
LMlib.c:11:45: error: request for member ‘subnetMask’ in something not a structure or union
LMlib.c:11:66: error: request for member ‘interface’ in something not a structure or union
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: why are you using `.h` file in compilation,you can do `cc` without it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have three problems: The first is that you don't use the array indexing properly. It's the `table` variable that is the array, not the structure member:

```
fscanf(f, "%s %d %d",
    table[i].address,
    &table[i].subnetMask,
    &table[i].interface);
```

The second problem is unrelated to your question, but may lead to trouble in the future. It's the include guard you have. The `#endif` should be at the *end* of the file, otherwise you only protect the single `#define` and nothing else.

The third, and most serious, problem is that you have one character to little in the `address` field. The maximum length of an IP-address is 15, which is correct, but if you want to treat it as a string you need space for the string terminator as well. Declare it as

```
address[MAX_IP_LENGTH + 1];
```

and it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about [operator precedence](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html). `.` has a higher precedence than `&`, so basically it says:

```
  &(table.address)[i]
```

and `table` is not a struct, but a pointer to struct. Then, you are wrong in your indexing, you are indexing the struct's members, not the array.

Rewrite like this:

```
  table[i].address
```